# Retrieving specific node from firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase in my android application. I need to get an object, i am searching with its email (attribute in the object).
this is my code of search:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Remorqueur");
Query queryRef=myRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(ed_mail.getText().toString());
```

If the object exists in my database I need to get the whole object back! how can I do it?

Comment: just attach a `ValueEventListener` to that query, and then you can check if the data exists or not using `if ( dataSnapshot.exists() )`

Comment: I need to delegate the action to a new activity when I found wht I'm looking for like this: query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { if(dataSnapshot.exists()) { Log.d("tester","existe"); rq=true; Intent i = new Intent(Accueil.this,Map_Client.class); } here in that function the intent doesn't work, what can I co?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  Please

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Remorqueur");
    Query query = profileDbRef
                .orderByChild("email")
                .equalTo(ed_mail.getText().toString());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot1.getKey() + "  " + dataSnapshot1.getValue(Profile.class)
                            .toString());
                   }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I need to delegate the action to a new activity when I found wht I'm looking for like this:
  query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        Log.d("tester","existe");
                        rq=true;
                        Intent i = new Intent(Accueil.this,Map_Client.class);
                    }
here in that function the intent doesn't work, what can I co?

Comment: I think your missing the startActivity(i) call after you initialize your intent

Answer (score 2):

should be able to do something like following

```
       queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    MyPojo app = childSnapshot.getValue(MyPojo.class);
                }
```